# Access Reserved Symbols Workaround not working as expected

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, alter-table

I would like to add a field with:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name ADD COLUMN ABCD012345(en) Memo;
```

[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/826763) is described what to do in that case:

> To work arond this problem, do not use special characters. If you must use special characters in query expressions, enclose the special characters in brackets ([]). For example, if you want to use the greater than sign (>), use [>].

As I understand it I would Need to Change it to:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name ADD COLUMN ABCD012345[(]en[)] Memo;
```

But this still leads to the same error: Syntax error in field Definition. If you Need a little more context: I do this with a `ADODB.Recordset` in a VBA macro.
Where do I go wrong? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround the entire name with brackets, not just the special characters:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Table_name ADD COLUMN [ABCD012345(en)] Memo;
-- Here --------------------------^--------------^
```